# passing multiple ajax result values to function called by event handler

Tags: javascript, ajax

i am writing custom javascript code (not jQuery) to deal with the response of an ajax request to match a given name to database names (name suggestions). I don't want to use a prebuilt plugin for this kind of work, as i want to be flexible for future modifications.

The ajax response has the following form (JSON array)

```
[{"ID":"ID1","name":"name1"},{"ID":"ID2","name":"name2"}]
```

I show you the following code sample to illustrate my current problem:

```
var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
var result = JSON.parse(response);
var number = result.length;
//box for namesuggestions 
var root = document.getElementById('namebox');
var list = document.createElement("ul");
for (var i=0;i<number;i++) {
            var element = document.createElement('li');
            element.onclick=function() {fillName(this.childNodes[0].nodeValue,this.childNodes[1].value);};
            //hidden input field for storage of ID
            var eInput = document.createElement('input');
            eInput.type = 'hidden';
            eInput.value = result[i].ID;
            //text field for storage of name
            var textElement = document.createTextNode(result[i].name);
            element.appendChild(textElement);
            element.appendChild(eInput);
            list.appendChild(element);              
}
root.appendChild(list);
```

My root element is the namebox, where i display the found list of name suggestions inside  a new created "ul" element. The list entries are created in the for loop. The `fillName` function will fill the chosen name into the appropriate `input` HTML tags, which was used for the ajax search. My problem is transferring the chosen `ID` and `name` to the `fillName` function in an easy way. As you can see i am using a hidden field for ID storage at the moment. To get access to `name` i use `this.childNodes[0].nodeValue`  and to `ID` `this.childNodes[1].value`.

Do you know a better way to transfer multiple values to functions called by event handlers, perhaps without using hidden fields or other html elements? For some reason i don't understand `element.onclick=function() {fillAuthor(result[i].name,result[i].ID);};` doesn't work.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the values like that won't work because by the time the click event handler is called, the for loop has finished and i=2 and there is no result[2].

Try doing it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/m8hwg/

```
var response = '[{"ID":"ID1","name":"name1"},{"ID":"ID2","name":"name2"}]';
var result = JSON.parse(response);
var number = result.length;
//box for namesuggestions 
var root = document.getElementById('namebox');
var list = document.createElement("ul");
for (var i=0;i<number;i++) {
            var element = document.createElement('li');
            element.onclick=function(res) {
                return function() {
                    console.log(res.name + ', ' + res.ID);
                }
            }(result[i]);
            //text field for storage of name
            var textElement = document.createTextNode(result[i].name);
            element.appendChild(textElement);
            list.appendChild(element);              
}
root.appendChild(list);
```

I switched fillAuthor for a console.log as I didn't know what fillAuthor would do.

Comment: so as far as i understand the event handler gets a function which returns a function, which takes its dependencies of the parent function. I dont get the syntax "function (res) {..}(result[i]);". Why can i use result[i] here, when i couldnt use it before ?

Comment: That function is being called immediately, which is why result[i] still contains the correct data, and result[i] is passed into the function to be used as a variable called res. 

And you're correct, that function returns a function which is the one used as the event handler.

Comment: which is just what i wanted, i will try that out now, so far it looks far more simpler than my approach. Thank you.